# Use Flash ActiveX as registration free

Tags: c++, com, activex

I have a game that uses flash activex component.

The problem is I need a specific version of flash.

I don't want to register the component over the existing higher version which can cause big security issues. I only want to use it for my application.

I've heard about registration free com technology using a manifest file for my application but didn't found any information on using it with flash activex or even its possible.

So my question is it possible to us the flash activex component as a registration free com? if yes then what are the requirements and how the manifest file should look as my try failed.

This is the .manifest I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="App" version="1.0.0.1" 
        processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" />

  <file name="Flash8.ocx">
    <comClass clsid="{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}" threadingModel="Both" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WARNING: Before I give you too much hope, I haven't tested this with Flash. I've tested it with smaller stuff where I "owned" both COM client and server. If Flash or some software it depends on requires registry settings other than pure COM and ActiveX controls, and even so, settings which are not available in manifests (e.g. categories), this might not work.

Define one [Assembly Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each file that Flash installs, that matches the COM settings that Flash registers during installation. If you know enough COM, [you'll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-[know](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-[where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-[to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-[look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Each of these manifest files must have a name different from the DLL.

Then, create an [Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your executable and add assembly dependencies after the file names you chose previously. If your application doesn't have an embedded manifest, this will be `<your-application>.exe.manifest`. If it has, you must make your build tool include these dependencies.

---

#### my-application.exe.manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <!--
    name: a string with the format: Organization.Division.Name
          Note: It doesn't matter
    version: 4 numbers between 0 and 65535 separated with dots
             Note: It doesn't matter
  -->
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="My.Application" version="1.0.0.0"/>

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>

      <!--
        name: a string with the format: Organization.Division.Name
              Note: It doesn't matter, but it must match what's in the manifest
        version: 4 numbers between 0 and 65535 separated with dots
                 Note: It doesn't matter, but it must match what's in the manifest
      -->
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Adobe.Flash.Control" version="8.0.42.0"/>

    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

---

#### Adobe.Flash.Control.manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <!--
    name: a string with the format: Organization.Division.Name
          Note: It doesn't matter, but it must match what's in the dependency
    version: 4 numbers between 0 and 65535 separated with dots
             Note: It doesn't matter, but it must match what's in the dependency
  -->
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Adobe.Flash.Control" version="8.0.42.0"/>

  <!-- file elements
    name: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\InprocServer32, default value
          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{TLBID}\{version}\{lcid}\win32, default value
          Note: Keep only the file names
          Note: In this case, the class factories and the type library happen to be in the same file
                Otherwise, the comClass and the typelib elements would be under different file elements
  -->

  <file name="Flash8g.ocx">

    <!-- comClass elements
      description:         HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}, default value
      clsid:               {CLSID}
      threadingModel:      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\InprocServer32, ThreadingModel
      tlbid:               HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\TypeLib, default value
      progid:              HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\ProgID, default value
      miscStatus:          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\MiscStatus, default value
      miscStatusIcon:      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\MiscStatus\4, default value
      miscStatusContent:   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\MiscStatus\1, default value
      miscStatusDocprint:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\MiscStatus\8, default value
      miscStatusThumbnail: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\MiscStatus\2, default value
    -->

    <comClass description="Shockwave Flash Object"
              clsid="{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"
              threadingModel="Apartment"
              tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"
              progid="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"
              miscStatus=""
              miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,setclientsitefirst">
      <progid>MacromediaFlashPaper.MacromediaFlashPaper</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.1</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.3</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.4</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.5</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7</progid>
      <progid>ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.8</progid>
    </comClass>

    <comClass description="Macromedia Flash Factory Object"
              clsid="{D27CDB70-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"
              threadingModel="Apartment"
              tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"
              progid="FlashFactory.FlashFactory">
      <progid>FlashFactory.FlashFactory.1</progid>
    </comClass>

    <!-- typelib elements
      tlbid:      {TLBID}
      version:    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\Version, default value
                  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\TypeLib, Version
      helpdir:    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{TLBID}\{version}\HELPDIR, default value
      resourceid: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{TLBID}\{lcid}, the subkey name
      flags:      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{TLBID}\{version}\Flags, default value
    -->

    <typelib tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}"
             version="1.0"
             helpdir="."
             resourceid="0"
             flags=""/>

    <!-- comInterfaceProxyStub elements
      iid:              {IID}
      name:             HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}, default value
      tlbid:            HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\TypeLib, default value
      baseInterface:    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\BaseInterface, default value
      numMethods:       HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\NumMethods, default value
      proxyStubClsid32: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\ProxyStubClsid32, default value
      threadingModel:   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{ProxyStubClsid32}\InprocServer32, ThreadingModel
    -->
    <!-- I found no need for any comInterfaceProxyStub -->
  </file>

  <!-- comInterfaceExternalProxyStub elements
    iid:              {IID}
    baseInterface:    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\BaseInterface, default value
    numMethods:       HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\NumMethods, default value
    name:             HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}, default value
    tlbid:            HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\TypeLib, default value
    proxyStubClsid32: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{IID}\ProxyStubClsid32, default value
  -->

  <!--
    I found these lingering from the current Flash installation I have.
    Please check if they are the same for Flash 8.
    If you don't need them, just remove them.

    These are comInterfaceExternalProxyStub and not comInterfaceProxyStub,
    because both {00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} (PSDispatch, IDispatch-based interfaces)
    and {00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} (PSOAInterface, Type Library interfaces)
    come with Windows.
  -->

  <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub iid="{86230738-D762-4C50-A2DE-A753E5B1686F}"
                                 name="IFlashObject"
                                 tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
                                 proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"/>

  <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub iid="{D27CDB6C-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
                                 name="IShockwaveFlash"
                                 tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
                                 proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"/>

  <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub iid="{D27CDB6D-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
                                 name="_IShockwaveFlashEvents"
                                 tlbid="{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
                                 proxyStubClsid32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"/>

</assembly>
```

---

I tested with the following bare-bones example, and it seems to work. Using Process Explorer, I can see that it loads the local Flash8g.ocx:

---

#### my-application.cpp

```c
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CoInitialize(NULL))) {
        CLSID clsid;
        // Both ways work
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.8", &clsid))) {
        /*if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}", &clsid))) {*/
            IDispatch *flash;
            // IID_PPV_ARGS is better, but doesn't exist in older SDKs
            /*if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&flash)))) {*/
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void**)&flash))) {
                OLECHAR name[] = L"ReadyState";
                LPOLESTR names[] = { &name[0] };
                DISPID dispid;
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr = flash->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, names, sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]), LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid))) {
                    DISPPARAMS params;
                    VARIANT result;
                    EXCEPINFO excepinfo;
                    UINT argerr;
                    params.rgvarg = NULL;
                    params.rgdispidNamedArgs = NULL;
                    params.cArgs = 0;
                    params.cNamedArgs = 0;
                    // Initialize out args due to buggy IDispatch implementations
                    VariantInit(&result);
                    excepinfo.wCode = 0;
                    excepinfo.wReserved = 0;
                    excepinfo.bstrSource = NULL;
                    excepinfo.bstrDescription = NULL;
                    excepinfo.bstrHelpFile = NULL;
                    excepinfo.dwHelpContext = 0;
                    excepinfo.pvReserved = NULL;
                    excepinfo.pfnDeferredFillIn = NULL;
                    excepinfo.scode = S_OK;
                    argerr = 0;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = flash->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &params, &result, &excepinfo, &argerr))) {
                        MessageBox(NULL, "The example ran to completion.", "Flash test", MB_OK);
                        VariantClear(&result);
                        SysFreeString(excepinfo.bstrSource);
                        excepinfo.bstrSource = NULL;
                        SysFreeString(excepinfo.bstrDescription);
                        excepinfo.bstrDescription = NULL;
                        SysFreeString(excepinfo.bstrHelpFile);
                        excepinfo.bstrHelpFile = NULL;
                    }
                }
                flash->Release();
                flash = NULL;
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't succeed. Hoped for more concrete example.

Comment: @Spider, I added example manifests. You may have to adjust for actual GUIDs, versions, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't manage to make it work yet, but I'll try to find the correct interface descriptions and hope it will work. Now its much clear.

Comment: @Spider, I've actually tested this with Flash 8.0.42.0 (at [Archived Flash Player versions](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)) and a bare-bones ` WinMain` with `CoInitialize` and `CoCreateInstance` worked.

Comment: Ah, I use C++ Builder with Auto ActiveX component generator. I'll try to change it